# how can i set current axes in user defined function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, undefined, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, axes

I am writing a program with gui . except functions that created automatic such as callbacks for objects in gui , i want to create user defined functions to use them in everywhere in this program . so i created meshing function that i write below .

```
function meshing(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8)

pmb = [( ( p1(1) + p5(1) ) / 2 ) ( ( p1(2) + p4(2) ) / 2 ) p1(3) ];
pmt = [( ( p1(1) + p5(1) ) / 2 ) ( ( p1(2) + p4(2) ) / 2 ) p2(3) ];

p23 = ( p2 + p3 ) / 2;

a = get(gcf);
axes(handles.axes3d);
scatter3(pmt(1),pmt(2),pmt(3))
```

but when i run it , this below error is showing

> Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
>
> Undefined variable "handles" or class "handles.axes3d".
>
> Error in SSF>meshing (line 897) axes(handles.axes3d);

but i have a axes3d in my gui . what can i do

Comment: You don't have an input argument named `handles`. Can you show where you define `meshing` to be the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that `handles` is not defined within your function because it is not passed as an input. If you look at all internally-defined callbacks, they have `handles` as an input.

Without seeing the exact code for how you're having your GUI call this `meshing` function, you could get the `guidata` of the GUI to have access to the `handles` variable from within your function.

```
handles = guidata(gcf);
```

Then you can use it within your function

```
scatter3(pmt(1), pmt(2), pmt(3), 'Parent', handles.axes3d)
```